# Auto-generate @version value in javadoc

Tags: android, javadoc

For the `@version` tag in javadoc, I use the same value as in `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`. I would like to inject that value, instead of changing every file for each release.

I tried:

`* @version {@value BuildConfig#VERSION_NAME}`

and

`* @version @versionName`  (and add `-tag versionName:a:"2.2.2"`)

but none of these works.

I could run `sed` just before the doc gets generated, but I would rather prefer something 'officially' supported.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second form, you can put your custom tag at the beginning of a javadoc line.

```
/**
 * This is a class of Foo<br/>
 *
 * @version
 *
 * @configVersion.
 */
```

Then use command `javadoc -version -tag configVersion.:a:"2.2.2"` to generate your javadoc, the custom tag should be handled in this way. Note the last dot(`.`) character in custom tag name, as the command `javadoc` suggests

> Note: Custom tags that could override future standard tags:  @configVersion. To avoid potential overrides, use at least one period character (.) in custom tag names.

Comment: I had to fix the formatting with `options.addStringOption("tag", "versionName:a:<dd>${android.getDefaultConfig().versionName.}</dd>")`, but it basically works. Thanks!